# Inside "row row-cols-*", width determination for "col" when there's sibling "col-*"

Tags: bootstrap-grid

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-4">
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
    <div class="col-6">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I thought the above code would have the same result as

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-4">
    <div class="col-2">Column</div>
    <div class="col-2">Column</div>
    <div class="col-6">Column</div>
    <div class="col-2">Column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But in fact it has the same result as

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-4">
    <div class="col-3">Column</div>
    <div class="col-3">Column</div>
    <div class="col-6">Column</div>
    <div class="col">Column</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand why.

[The documentation of .row-cols-*](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/#row-columns) says

> Use the responsive .row-cols-* classes to quickly set the number of columns that best render your content and layout.

So I thought:

1. `row-cols-4` means 1 row shoud have 4 `<div class="col">` (or `col-*`).
2. The third div has `col-6` so its width would be 50% (6 out of 12) of the parent container.
3. The other 3 `<div class="col">` equally share the remaining 50% width.

But the truth is the 4th div wraps, leaving the first 3 divs in the first line, among which the first 2 each occupies 25% of the horizontal space.

Can somebody help me reason about this? Have I misunderstood the meaning of `row-cols-4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common misconception.

`row-cols-*` sets the columns on the row.

So for example: `row-cols-4` would mean the `row` should be divided into **4** columns, thus each column would implicitly be a `col-3`. Now, when you do a `row-cols-4` and put `col`, `col`, `col-6` and `col` inside it, you are giving the 3rd column (`col-6`) double of what is assigned to each column in the row.
Now what you thought was this would distribute the remaining **6** columns into **3** and give **2** to each of the remaining. That isn't so. The other columns still get **3** column spaces. Because that is what we assigned as a minimum when we did `row-cols-4`. Anything extra will wrap, as it is doing.

I hope this clears something up.